# A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later

Tags: magento2.3, catalogsearch

I have set min query length in catalog search to 3.And if search less than this characters then i get this above error. I have used mageplaza extentions. I tried with disable also.But same issue remains. Is there any other issue for this.

Comment: look in the `exception.log` file for more details

Comment: Framework\Data\Collection\\AbstractDb->_renderFilters() called at [app\/code\/Mageplaza\/LayeredNavigation\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Fulltext\/Collection.php